# Tracking of directing user to Google Play Store

Tags: java, android-studio, google-play

I've built a app that directs users to other apps on the play store. Im looking to be able to see which users I directed to this other app. Im using android studio

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to know which or how many users went from your app to the play store, you can achieve this by event tracking for example via  ([Firebase Analytics](https://firebase.google.com/products/analytics?gclid=Cj0KCQjwuMuRBhCJARIsAHXdnqOFeJUI9874JEv-0iGXHE31CUSFdJ_a--_V46wq8xVobXD5m8ZiS3YaAtr1EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)). But as soon as your users have left your app, there is no way of tracking what they once left. For example, if there is a list of apps in your app, each linking to their corresponding play store entry, you can track clicks on the different links inside of your app. But as soon as the user clicked on that link and went to the play store, you can't track what he is doing there or if he is downloading the app (as long as you are not the developer of the app the user then downloads)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Exactly the answer I was looking for